# Qtranslate-xp (qtranslate-plus) url work with qtranslate-slug plugins

Tags: wordpress

I am using one plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-xp/ for my WordPress site. Now I want about us page URL in three language. Means I want unique slug for about us in each language like english, deutche, etc.

Does any one know how to do that? Also, I have come to know about qtranslate-slug plugins but that is not working with qtranslate-xp. so can you please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your problem, you can replace Qtranslate-XP with mqTranslate (upgrade on 2015-2-27) and you can use Qtraslate-slug.

Qtranslate-XP and mqTranslate use same tags.